# How to display dummy data in a JSON object in the html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html

I am trying to display some dummy data, which is stored in JSON object. I am a newbie to this subject. So I don't understand clearly how to proceed with this.

However I wrote a javascript function and ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = {
      "id": 1,
      "schedule": 1,
      "channel": "AXN",
      "fromDate": "2018-01-19",
      "toDate": "2018-01-31",
      "startTime": "11:00:00",
      "endTime": "12:00:00",
      "type": "TVC",
      "mediaFile": 1
    }

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: URI.customSchedule.getCustomScheduleUrl(),
         data: data,
         beforeSend: function () {

         },
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         cache: false,
         timeout: 600000,
         success: function (data) {
            data.channel = $('#selectChannel').val();
            data.fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
            date.toDate = $('#toDate').val();
            date.startTime = $('#startTime').val();
            date.endTime = $('#endTime');
         },
         error: function (e) {

         }
     });
 });
```

This is how assigned the data in the JSON object to the html fields and this does not works.

```
data.channel = $('#selectChannel').val();
data.fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
date.toDate = $('#toDate').val();
date.startTime = $('#startTime').val();
date.endTime = $('#endTime');
```

Can someone help me with this and explain the mistakes I did ? Please help me to display the values stored in the JSON object in html fields.

Edit:

While I debug the code, the debug point does not go inside the Ajax call. What is the issuee here?

Comment: You can log both data in success function and error in error function to see what happen

Answer (score 2):

To assign to HTML fields do this.

```
$('#selectChannel').val(data.channel);
$('#fromDate').val(data.fromDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

In jquery there is same function that get and set the values in the element. `val()` is a common function that will get the value from specific element and also set the value to that element.

If you use `val()` with one parameter as a value then it will set the value to that HTML element so what you are doing inside `success` is getting the value from the element with `id=selectChannel`. You need to do

```
$('#selectChannel').val(data.channel);
```

To set the value `data.channel` into the element with `id=selectChannel`. And similar for other elements also.

Comment: Although I did like this, those values are not shown in the html

Comment: can you please console log the `data` inside success and comment that JSON here. So that i can debug more for you.

Comment: @sndu Maybe the data still JSON string. You need to use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert it to javascript object

Comment: @sndu any progress?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal no, nothing

Comment: Console log the `data` inside the `success` function and send me that JSON.